# Methods Declaration and formation

Tags: c#, arrays, string, methods

The question is-
Make a method called ReadInFile.
It should take in 3 variables:

1. string fileName, which is the name of the file
2. int height, which is the height of the table
3. int width, which is the width of the table

It returns a 2-dimensional array of type string. The size of the array is based on the variables height and width.

Use this method to read in one of the files downloaded from Learn and display the contents to the Console Window.

How could I possibly write this code? Assume that the files downloaded have dimensions of (6,6). The downloaded file has a name "letters.csv".
Here is what I wrote:

```
 public string[, ] ReadInFile(string fileName, int height, int width) 
 {
   string[, ] apj = new string[height, width];
   return apj[height, width];

   StreamReader fileName = new StreamReader(@"letters.csv");
   for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
   {
     for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) 
     {
       string yo = fileName.ReadLine();
       Console.WriteLine(yo);
     }
   }

   fileName.Close();
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample input file?

Comment: is this line `return apj[height,width];` expected after initialization?

Comment: It returns a 2-dimensional array of type string. @HariPrasad.

Comment: @SureshKumarVeluswamy. I don't have the required reputation points. :(. I can mail you them though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that it's a CSV from the filename you gave in question. So in this case you can use `.Split(',')` on each line to get the values and then store them in your array:

```
public string[,] ReadInFile(string fileName, int height, int width)
{
    var parsedFile = new string[height, width];

    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

    var row = 0;

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        var split = line.Split(',');

        var column = 0;

        foreach (var value in split)
        {
            parsedFile[row, column] = value;
            column++;
        }

        row++;
    }

    return parsedFile;
}
```

Comment: When I call this method in the main method, the compiler gives me an Error CS1501:No overload for method 'ReadInFile' takes '2' arguments .

Comment: You're not calling it correctly then - needs to be called with three arguments, i.e, `var result = ReadInFile("fileName", 6, 6);`